# Usage of string::c_str on temporary string

Tags: c++, destructor, temporary-objects

In regards to when temporary objects get destroyed, is this valid:

```
FILE *f = fopen (std::string ("my_path").c_str (), "r");
```

Will the temporary be destroyed immediately after having evaluated the first argument to `fopen` or after the `fopen` call.

Testing with the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
struct A {
        ~A() { printf ("~A\n"); }
        const char *c_str () { return "c_str"; }
};
void foo (const char *s) { printf ("%s\n", s); }
int main () {
        foo (A().c_str());
        printf ("after\n");
        return 0;
}
```

gives:

```
c_str
~A
after
```

which indicates that the whole statement is first evaluated, and then any temporaries are destroyed. Is this ordering mandated by the standard or implementation-specific?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The temporary will be destroyed at the end of the expression, namely the `;` semicolon. **So you are safe.**

> § 12.2 ... Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in
>   evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the
>   point where they were created. This is true even if that evaluation
>   ends in throwing an exception.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this ordering mandated by the standard or implementation-specific?

[class.temporary]/3

> Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step
>   in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.

so its mandated by the standard