# C++ parentheses around string

Tags: c++, string

If I have a function `myfunc(const char *x, int y)` and a `std::string` variable `mystring`, can I call `myfunc()` like `myfunc((mystring + "string constant").c_str(), 4)`? If not, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried it? What did you find? If you are afraid to experiment, it will be hard to learn.

Comment: You can call `c_str()` on the parenthesized expression, it will compile, but it won't do any good.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146647/usage-of-stringc-str-on-temporary-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you should not call it like this.

```
myfunc((mystring + "string constant").c_str(), 4)
```

As temporary is created to hold `mystring + "string constant"`. And when you apply `c_str` on that temporary, it would return the internal handle of that string. So, don't be surprised if you get undesired results.

Comment: Is the constant still passed along?

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense to me. `c_str()` doesn't return an "internal handle" whatever that is meant to mean. It returns a null terminated `const char*` containing the contents of the string. You say to beware of unexpected results. Perhaps you could explain what could not be expected. I don't see any scope for anything unexpected here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan There's a member function in string class operator const char*(), which returns "data" a char* pointer data member used to store string's data. And c_str() does call this operator. That' what I mean when I say handle of string.Please let me know if I'm wrong somewhere...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "I don't see any scope for anything unexpected here".I once had similar case with undefined behavior. Undefined means it worked during development, worked during testing, but blowed up on one of customer faces. That's why I said don't be surprised if you get undesired results. I always prefer to keep a distance from these potential ambiguities.

Comment: You are wrong. There's no undefined behaviour. Your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the option, change `myfunc` to:

```
myfunc(std::string const& x, int y);
```

Then, you can use:

```
myfunc((mystring + "string constant"), 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can safely call the temporary in the function:

```
myfunc((mystring + "string constant").c_str(), 4);
```

as long as you are only reading the string from `const char *x` and not attempting to modify it using non-const cast. The temporary will be destroyed at the end of full expression expression. As others have said the good practice would be better to use a `std::string`.